# Create a custom Search Center

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have a client that wants a custom search center that uses the theme that their site uses instead of the default theme. They also want custom navigation tabs that reflect the ones in thier sites in the search center navigation.

I do not want to apply these changes to all sites, just the ones the clients wants.

How do I create a new search center and how best can I apply it to specific sites?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar request. I made one custom application page and handle search request in c#, passing search text in query string. For making search programmatically in MOSS I used tool from codeplex MOSSSearchCoder.

Maybe you can find something for your custom search center in http://sct.codeplex.com/. I only tried MOSSSearchCoder and it's more than good.